# Exclude results in a sql query

Tags: sql

I have a tiny table like this:

```
****************************
| Name | old_v   | new_v   *
****************************
|ITEM1 | new     | passed  *
|ITEM1 | failed  | passed  *
|ITEM2 | new     | failed  *
|ITEM1 | passed  | failed  *
|ITEM3 | new     | blocked *
|ITEM2 | failed  | failed  *
|ITEM4 | new     | new     *
```

I tried to build a sql query which shows me all the items, that **never** had the status **passed**. 
According to the above example, the output should be:

```
ITEM2
ITEM3
```

However, this query:

```
SELECT Name FROM table WHERE old_v NOT IN 'passed' AND new_v NOT IN 'passed'
```

Does not give me the correct result. Do you have any clue how to solve this?

Comment: how about `SELECT Name FROM table WHERE 'passed' NOT IN (old_v, new_v)`?

Comment: Hi Kenney, this similar to my try and it does still contain wrong values

Comment: This looks like a good opportunity for some database normalization.  Name seems to be a logical key, but there is repetition.  So why not split the values off into a different table with a foreign key pointing back to this one, then I imagine the query will not give you this problem as you will only find each name once :)

Comment: Why would ITEM4 not be in the result set?

Comment: @dufresnb: As long as name is a fixed identifier, there is nothing to "normalize" here. An additional technical ID would be "repeated" just the same. But yes, if name is just some data, subject to change, then it should have a table on ist own with a fix identifier such as the item number or a technical ID.

Comment: your query should return each row without a value of 'passed' in either field, but won't exclude each item with other rows with a value of 'passed.'  You need to identify the rows with 'passed' values, then exclude them from the set of all items.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner are you trying to correct my definition of normalize?  It sounds like you refuted my point before reiterating my suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return a row if no row with same name has passed:

```
select distinct t1.name
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.name = t1.name
                    and 'passed' in (t2.old_v, t2.new_v))
```

Comment: Probably not. And since no dbms is specified that question can't really be answered.

Answer (score 3):

In your case where all data needed is in the same table and you just need the name, you can aggregate your data: group by name and remove unwanted records with `HAVING`:

```
select name
from mytable
group by name
having count(case when old_v = 'passed' then 1 end) = 0
   and count(case when new_v = 'passed' then 1 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    item
FROM
    [TABLE] t LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
        item
    FROM
        [TABLE]
    WHERE
        old_v = 'passed' OR
        new_v = 'passed') p ON
    t.item = p.item
WHERE
    p.item IS NULL
GROUP BY
    item
```

Comment: The charm about SQL is to only have to say *what* to do ("get all items for which **not exist** any passed entry" or "get all items that are **not in** the list of passed items") and not *how* to do it. But this is what you are doing here. You are using a trick which is usually used on early DBMS versions where the developers put all their effort into making joins hum, but rather neglected IN and EXISTS so far. So you make the DBMS choose a join in order to check for existence. I would only use this technique when forced by real bad performance of a query.

Comment: As to `GROUP BY`: you would use this when aggregating *records*. Here you only have *one* column, so you only want to get *distinct* values. Use `DISTINCT` hence.

Comment: my understanding was that GROUP BY was less performant than DISTINCT because DISTINCT included a sort function that wasn't performed by the GROUP BY.  Does having only one column mean a sort isn't performed?

Comment: You just shouldn't care how some DBMS implements this feature. One DBMS may sort the data, another might use a hash technique - who cares? All you want the query to do is get **distinct** results, so use `DISTINCT`. Think straight-forward when using SQL :-)